# Kubernetes Ingress - referring external path to another path in service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have multiple namespaces which utilize different services
Some of these services expose the same paths, i.e. `/ready`

I'de like to create an ingress rule per namespace/service so the **external** path of `namespaceA/ready` will actually go to the service under `namespaceA` at `/ready` path

I read about [rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) but if I understand it correctly, it will redirect `namespaceA/ready` to `/ready` globally, meaning it will just act as if the path was `/ready`, regardless to the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [Lentil1016](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8884013/lentil1016) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57691517/9521610), here is the example of the same [rewrite](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md#rewrite-target) solution for [nginx-ingress-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/deploy/index.md).

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: 'false'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: myapp
  namespace: namespaceA
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp
          servicePort: 80
        path: /namespaceA(/|$)(.*)
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: myapp
  namespace: namespaceB
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp
          servicePort: 80
        path: /namespaceB(/|$)(.*)
```

For example, the ingress definition above will result in the following rewrites:

For destination service myapp in the namespace namespaceA:

```
mydomain.io/namespaceA rewrites to mydomain.io/ 
mydomain.io/namespaceA/ rewrites to mydomain.io/
mydomain.io/namespaceA/ready/ rewrites to mydomain.io/ready/
```

For destination service myapp in the namespace namespaceB:

```
mydomain.io/namespaceB rewrites to mydomain.io/
mydomain.io/namespaceB/ rewrites to mydomain.io/
mydomain.io/namespaceB/ready/ rewrites to mydomain.io/ready/
```

**Note**: You may need to use nginx-config [ConfigMap](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap.md#ssl-redirect) to completely switch off [ssl-redirect](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect) for nginx-ingress-controller.
**Note**: There are two kinds of nginx-ingress-controllers, [kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/deploy/index.md) and [nginxinc](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/installation.md). ConfigMap options and [annotations](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/configmap-and-annotations.md) could be different for each of them.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
  namespace: nginx-ingress  # <--- or ingress-nginx, depends on your installation
data:
  redirect-to-https: "false"
  ssl-redirect: "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. But you may have a little misunderstanding between `rewrite` and `redirect`. Rewrite rules won't cause redirect, it rewrite the request then send it to the specific backend. It's totally reasonable and common to configure two rewrite rules rewriting two paths with the same suffix to two different backend.

Rewrite works like this:

```
$ curl mydomain.io/test/moretest
404 page not found

$ kubectl logs test-server
Request method=GET path=/moretest status=404 user-agent=curl/7.29.0
```

redirect however, works like this:

```
# curl mydomain.io/test/moretest
Moved Permanently
# curl mydomain.io/moretest
404 page not found

$ kubectl logs test-server
Request method=GET path=/test/moretest status=302 user-agent=curl/7.29.0
Request method=GET path=/moretest status=404 user-agent=curl/7.29.0
```

I'm not familiar with Nginx. I know how to achieve this with Traefik, though. For instance, this `yaml` file will do:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myappA
  namespace: namespaceA
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: PathPrefixStrip
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /namespaceA
        backend:
         serviceName: myapp
         servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myappB
  namespace: namespaceB
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: PathPrefixStrip
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /namespaceB
        backend:
         serviceName: myapp
         servicePort: 80
```

- All the request for `/namespaceA/ready` will be rewritten to `/ready` then being sent to `myapp` in `namespaceA`.
- All the request for `/namespaceB/ready` will be rewritten to `/ready` then being sent to `myapp` in `namespaceB`.

Comment: Thank you, where do you tell `PathPrefixStrip` what to strip? is it simply the `/path`? anyway, this is exactly what I want but I can't find how to do the same in `NGINX` controllers.